# Canvas in Dart: how to load and display image

Tags: html, canvas, dart

At first taking CanvasElement from DOM and getting canvas context:

```
CanvasElement canvas = querySelector('canvas');
CanvasRenderingContext2D context = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Generating image from source:

```
ImageElement image = new ImageElement(src: 'placeholder.png');
```

Than listening to onLoad event and trying to draw image:

```
image.onLoad.listen((e) {
   context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
});
```

Doesn't work, canvas still blank. 
I am sure image is loaded properly because i am able to place it in DOM:

```
image.onLoad.listen((e) {
   document.body.children.add(image);
});
```

Also i think canvas and context initialized properly because i am able to draw rectangle:

```
context.fillRect (10, 10, 55, 50);
```

I've tried to google similiar problems, but all their solution was just image.onLoad.listen() which i already had in my code.

Comment: Exacly same javascript analog works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/rxt3y8dr/1/ Could it be some dart releated issue?

Comment: Your code is fine and it works for me. What happens if you use `context.drawImageScaled(image, 0, 0, 55, 50)` instead?

Comment: Perfect, so you have to make sure that both image actual sizes and canvas sizes match.

Answer (score 2):

(Copied from comments so this question appears answered!)

The dimensions for your image and canvas probably do not match. You can either resize your image, or use  `context.drawImageScaled(image, 0, 0, 55, 50)` to scale the image when rendering.